# Is there a formal definition of signature of natural selection?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection

I’ve searched for a definition of `signature of natural selection`. Unfortunately, I haven’t found any formal definition of it.

The signature of positive selection on standing genetic variation. I found [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42029/what-test-to-apply-to-detect-genomic-signatures-of-selection) that links to an article measuring the signature with an Fst and a Linkage Disequilibrium test.

Are we looking at only some frequency of alleles in different populations? Is the signature only a fixation of alleles in a population where this allele was positively selected?

Another [article](http://www.eve.ucdavis.edu/gmcoop/publications/Przeworski_Coop_Wall_05.pdf) says:

> A single beneficial substitution can be detected in polymorphism
>   data, so long as it occurred recently. The fixation of a favorable
>   allele in a population distorts patterns of variation at linked
>   sites, thereby leaving a distinguishing signature that lasts up to
>   about 104 generations in humans or about 106 in Drosophila
>   melanogaster (Przeworski 2002). In principle, targets of positive
>   selection can therefore be identified by searching polymorphism data
>   for regions that harbor this signature (Nair et al. 2003; Wright et
>   al. 2005).

Is it always in linkage disequilibrium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would personally explain what a genetic signature is:

---

A **genetic signature** of a certain type of **evolutionary history** (type of **selection** or **demography**) refers to the effect that this specific type of evolutionary history has on genomic properties of populations today.

We are interested in understanding such signatures because knowing the association between a number of evolutionary histories and their genetic signature allows us to reconstruct the evolutionary history of a population just by looking at the genomics of this population.

For example, recent selective sweep, population expansion after a recent bottleneck and/or linkage to a swept gene are all causing negative Tajima's D. Balancing selection and/or sudden population contraction are causing positive Tajima's D. In this example Tajima's D is a statistics that is used to measure this so-called signature of the different process.

---

The above was NOT a citation. I am NOT aware of any publications defining rigorously what a genetic signature is. I think it is not so uncommon for authors to use a term without strictly defining it. As long as the unclarity of the definition does not yield to limit cases and misunderstanding, then it is totally fine.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this? I mean, is this a quote? Is it like the [gene signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_signature) or the [genomic signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomic_signature)?

Comment: Nope I don't! Feels like we already had this discussion on another post $\ddot \smile$ This is why I said `I would explain...` and `I am not aware of any publication defining rigorously what a genetic signature is`. I tried to make this point even clearer.

Comment: Haha! Thanks a lot for your contribution! I'm going to continue the research until I find something. This concept is, most of the time, used with selective sweep, right? For instance I found _Nielsen, R. 2005. Molecular signatures of natural selection_ and _Hohenlohe, P. A., P. C. Phillips, and W. A. Cresko. 2010. Using Population Genomics to Detect Selection in Natural Populations: Key Concepts and Methodological Considerations_ with nice figures (fig 1 and [4](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3016716/figure/F4/) respectively) Seems that these images could represent a "signature".